# Make Firebase realtime database returning only allowed fields

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following database structure

```
{
"users": {
   "$uid": {
     "externalId": "val",
     "email": "mail@example.com",
     "items": {
       "$itemId": {
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

I need to allow any authenticated user to read any user's `items` while querying this user's node by `externalId`, but not to allow reading `email` field

This is the code for this query

```
val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
val query = reference.orderByChild("externalId").equalTo(extId)
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val list = mutableListOf<Item>()
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (user in dataSnapshot.children) {
                for (itemSnapshot in user.child("items").children) {
                    val item = itemSnapshot.getValue(Item::class.java)
                    item?.let {
                        list.add(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        result.value = list
    }
    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
    }
})
```

This is database rules

```
{
    "users": {
       ".indexOn": "externalId",
       ".read": "auth !== null && query.orderByChild == 'externalId' && query.equalTo !== null"
       "$uid": {
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
     }
}
```

But this allows reading full `$uid` node including `email`. How to configure rules in a way that database returns `$uid` node without `email` field?

Comment: I would split user_data and items nodes, so you can set different rules for them. Also to me the structure doesn't seem right, these ideally are separate "tables"

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, I think a solution to your problem is considering a different data structure

```
{
"users": {
   "$uid": {
     "email": "mail@example.com",
           }
         }
"items": {
    "$uid":{
     "externalId": "val",
     "$itemId": {
           }
}
```

You can set the read on users node to `"$uid === auth.uid"`, and to true on the items